# replace occurence strings in UILabel for striketrough text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to strike trough a part of the text in a `UILabel` after it has been initialized.

I've tried this:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *uppercaseStrikeText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"one uppercase character"];
[uppercaseStrikeText addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [uppercaseStrikeText length])];

self.passwordLabel.text = [self.passwordLabel.text
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"one uppercase character"
                           withString:@"one uppercase character" options:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0, [uppercaseStrikeText length])];
```

However, this gives the warning:

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString *const __strong' to parameter of type 'NSStringCompareOptions' (aka 'enum NSStringCompareOptions')
```

and however this doesn't crash my code, it doesn't work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UILabel.attributedText property and construct proper NSAttributedString

```
NSString *originalText = self.label.text;
NSRange strikeRange = [originalText rangeOfString:@"string to be striked"];
if (strikeRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:originalText attributes:attributesOfNormalText];
    [attributedString setAttributes:attributesOfStrikeText range:substringRange];
    self.label.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

Comment: Hm this gives me the same warning.. I realize that the code I provided wasn't able to test 100% because I forgot to add `uppercaseStrikeText`.

Comment: @bdv `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` is not a valid option to `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`, it's an attribute of NSAttributedString. You should construct and attributed string and put it into label.attributedText property, that's the only way. 
From your example:
`[uppercaseStrikeText addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [uppercaseStrikeText length])];

self.passwordLabel.attributedText = uppercaseStrikeText;`

Comment: Allright, but that would replace the entire label, and I only want to replace a part of it. Say the label says "enter a uppercase and a lowercase character". Then I want to cross the "uppercase" part

Comment: @bdv use `rangeOfString:` as I did in my answer to get the range of substring that needs to be altered. If there could be several occasions, use `rangeOfString:options:range:` to enumerate them all